# alert inside ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using an ajax call to call a php function where inside it I have an alert.
But the alert not fire but return me the code of the javascript (seen inside console).
How can I use an laert inside an ajax call?

Please don't answer to use function success to check my data etc etc.. because I need alert inside the call please.

This is my code simplified:

```
$('.form-booking').each(function(){
        $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: someurl.php'',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    });
```

php part in `someurl.php`

```
<?php
....
//some code
....
if($some_condition){
          ?>
          <script>
          if (confirm('Do you wanna go over?')) {
              //other code
          } else {
              window.location.href = 'otherurl.php';
          }
          </script>
          <?php
}
?>
```

This code does't show alert if the condition is true but I see inside console in tab `Net` the response and the code of the script in javascript

Comment: why can you not use the success callback?

Comment: you need to run the javascript that you get.. eval is an option but it's dangerous

Comment: because I need it inside my code to call other function and means that I have to refactoring all code if I have to use success function. If there is no way I make a refactoring but if is possible I wanna know how @VincentRamdhanie

Comment: not a good solution for my purpose @PiotrKaluza

Comment: To be able to run javascript, you'd need to add it to the html at the very least.

Comment: You could try to set `dataType: 'script'` but you need to lose the `<script>` and ` </script>` blocks on your PHP side.

Comment: if the ajax returns a script you need to run it (eval or add to html or somehow) , no other way around it. You can't run javascript during the ajax call, you either run it before, or after. as far as refactoring other functions - why not have a separate entity (function, object) that encapsulates the logic and just call into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<php

// some code

echo $some_condition
```

Then in your main file in your success function:

```
      function(data){
      if(data){
      if (confirm('Do you wanna go over?')) {
          //other code
      } else {
          window.location.href = 'otherurl.php';
      }
      }
```

Comment: I have specified into the question that I don't want to use success function please

Comment: You're not going to get the javascript to come through from someurl.php, you could always break someurl.php into 2 files and use another ajax call based on what the user clicks. That would keep you from having to refactor....